# Mocking internal function call in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, testing, jvm, ktor, mockk

I am a complete beginner in terms of Kotlin and I am finding some issues while trying to test out a `Ktor` based application.

I have a file in my `endpoints` package localized at `org.example.endpoints.hello`

this file contains a `fun Application.hello` that implements an endpoint for my application.

This endpoint acts as a wrapper for another API, so inside that same file I have a

```kotlin
fun callOtherAPI(): ResponseContainer {
  // networking stuff
  return ResponseContainer(message: "some stuff")
}
```

This function gets called inside the Application's function `routing` implementation as such:

```kotlin
    routing {
        get("/hello") {
            call.respond(callOtherAPI())
        }
    }
```

**Now to the issue:**

My test currently looks like this:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testHello() = testApplication {
        application {
            hello()
        }
        mockkStatic(::callOtherAPI)
        every { callOtherAPI() } returns ResponseContainer("hello")
        print(callOtherAPI()) // This actually returns the mocked response, which is what I want
        client.get("/hello").apply {
            val expected = ResponseContainer("hello")
            val response = jacksonObjectMapper().readValue<ResponseContainer>(bodyAsText())
            assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, status)
            assertEquals(expected.message, response.message) // This assert fails because the internal call to callOtherAPI() is not being mocked.
        }
    }
```

So the problem that I am facing is that while the mocked function **is** being mocked within the context of the test, **it is not** being mocked when called internally by the `routing` implementation.

Can someone point me to good documentation to figure this out, I've been at it for the past two hours to no avail :/

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure even what mocking framework you are using.  Try this: https://mockk.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a parameter for the `callOtherAPI` function in the `hello` method. For the production and testing environment you will pass different functions in this case. Here is your code rewritten:

```
@Test
fun testHello() = testApplication {
    application {
        // hello(::callOtherAPI) this call will be for the production environment
        hello { ResponseContainer("hello") }
    }


    client.get("/hello").apply {
        assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, status)
        assertEquals("{\"message\":\"hello\"}", bodyAsText())
    }
}

data class ResponseContainer(val message: String)

fun Application.hello(callOtherAPI: () -> ResponseContainer) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        jackson()
    }

    routing {
        get("/hello") {
            call.respond(callOtherAPI())
        }
    }
}

fun callOtherAPI(): ResponseContainer {
    // networking stuff
    return ResponseContainer("some stuff")
}
```